# Is it rude to use idownvotedbecau.se?

Tags: discussion

A comment of mine [see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075887/8330162] got deleted (probably marked as rude) because of linking to http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

1. How do I see my deleted comments plus reason for the deletion?
2. Is it really rude to link to that website? I have seen it so many times and it really helped me when I was new to the site.

Comment: No, you can't see your deleted comments, nor the reason for their deletion. It is more likely they were deleted as "no longer needed" than "rude or unkind".

Comment: Better to leave personalized feedback and to avoid referring to votes when commenting. Several mods have mentioned that they delete those comments on sight when flagged.

Comment: @yivi: Thanks for the management summary!

Comment: Is it rude? No, not really. Will it be perceived as rude? There is a good chance. And when there is a good chance that a comment is perceived as rude... there is a good chance it will be deleted.

Comment: @yivi My userscript [Comment History Checker](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Comment-History-Checker) will show you comments of yours that have been deleted, along with *some* indication of the cause